# Is there a way to set the focus distance for Android camera?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

In the Android camera API, there seem to be some relevant functions that might imply I can set the focus distance on a camera:

```
Camera.setParameters(Camera.Parameters params)
Camera.Parameters.getFocusDistances(float[] output)
```

and the static value:

```
Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_FIXED
```

I want to be able to actually set the focus distance programmatically but I can't figure out what the parameter would be. Does anyone know how I would do this?

Answer (score 1):

No there's no API method to set the focus to a particular distance. These just tell you about the focus that has been found, by perhaps auto-focus.

Comment: What about Camera.setParameters? Isn't there a way to set it in there (perhaps in an undocumented setting)?

Comment: That's what I'm referring to. If there is any device-specific setting, I don't know of it, and it would of course not work on most devices.